# Update Eclipse RCP UI after job is complete

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have a long running process that retrieves records from a database and I don't want the UI to freeze.  I have moved the actual retrieve to a job.  How do I know when the Job has finished so I can update the UI with the results of the query?

In the sample code below once dbJob completes, I want the updateUI method called.

```java
public void updateUI() {
    if (viewList.size() > 0) {
        ((StackLayout) compositeStacked.getLayout()).topControl = compositeTable;
    } else {
        ((StackLayout) compositeStacked.getLayout()).topControl = compositeNoRows;
    }
    compositeStacked.layout();

    // set input and refresh
    tableViewer.setInput(motorList);
    tableViewer.refresh();
}


public refresh() {
    Job dbJob = new Job("List Retrieve") {
        @Override
        protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
            try {
                viewList = Databasequery
            } catch (BusinessException e) {
                StatusManager.getManager().handle(
                        new Status(IStatus.ERROR, Activator.PLUGIN_ID, "Could not retrieve the list", e),
                        StatusManager.LOG | StatusManager.SHOW);
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                logger.warn("Error retrieving list", t);
            }
            return Status.OK_STATUS;
        }
    };

    dbJob.schedule();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `IJobChangeListener` to listen for changes to the job's state. There is a standard `JobChangeAdapter` class that provides defaults for the methods you don't need so you can do something like:

```java
  dbJob.addJobChangeListener(new JobChangeAdapter() {
     @Override
     public void done(IJobChangeEvent event)
     {
       // Listener does not run in UI thread so use asyncExec

       Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable()
        {
          @Override
          public void run()
          {
            updateUI();
          }
        });
     }
   });
```

Add the listener **before** you schedule the job.